# I18n Browser Based editor for Rails 3 project ( that runs local no saas projects )?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

Is there any gem out that can edit I18n translations from the browser? I have digged github and found all repo's to be outdated and rails 2.x. 
I already know copycopter and other online translation services, *i want to translate the text of my own app locally from the browser*

Like 
https://github.com/n1k/i18n_locale_editor

anyone suggestions for rails 3? Magento styled inline editing, click and edit would be even more great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [phrase](https://phraseapp.com/), great service.

Comment: yeah.. its even more expensive than all other services combined, Don't want to upload my language files need a local edit but thx for noting this service wich is toooo expensive;) now this but then opensource?

Comment: Yes.. but they get access to all my locales, I can't for reasons afford having external sources have access to them. but this IS the best implementation I have seen